# Changing NavigationView TintColor with code rather than XAML

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I was wondering if it is possible to change the colour of the NavigationView in code.

Currently i have a XAML override within the App.xaml page that over-rides the tintcolour of the NavigationView.

```
<AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="Red" TintOpacity=".3"/>

<AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="Red" TintOpacity=".3"/>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to achieve something similar in code. Im looking specifically for a way to edit the TintColor.

The end goal of this is to allow a ColorPicker to change the TintColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your pane background as transparent.

```
<AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
           TintColor="Transparent" TintOpacity="0" Opacity="0"/>
```

after this the pane background will become completely transparent for anything below it. So now we can change the background of the **NavigationView** itself and it will be reflective on the pane as well.

so in your code behind where you want to change the pane background just set the background of **NavView.Background**

Comment: Oh! That is something i would never have thought of! Thank you!